# Div tag not moving anything

Tags: html, css

I've contained items in a div tag and I'm trying to make the images and text go horizontal and thus hit the max length of the page, and overflow into the next line causing into a horizontal list rather than vertical (in my theory anyway). However, when I try to make any changes to this div tag I have no change at all?

CSS:

```
.change{
width: 100%
min-width: 400px;
max-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
white-space: pre-wrap;}
```

HTML and full code in comments: 
&

http://jsfiddle.net/g2m7fsoe/1/

Comment: You'll have to be a bit clearer. What do you mean by `them`? The images? The text? Both?

Comment: When I tried to do that previously it just run the code and didn't display anything there?

Comment: yes, that's fine. We need to see the code here on the site.

Comment: It is optimal to see `actual code` in your question, not just an offsite link.

Comment: the issue is as there's large amounts of repetitive code which may/may not be useful it would take a large amount of time to indent it all

Comment: Indentation take almost no time in an editor (select the block of code and a hit tab) and you only need to paste a representative portion that shows the issue, you are trying to fix, no one want to see your entire code file and css - just a portion that shows the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Give each item a `div` inside the main `div` and give `float:left;` to the items `div`

Comment: if you are using id learn to use '#' for the class and not '.'

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your mark-up and CSS in your fiddle.

You effectively have this

```
<div id= "flag">
   <div id="flag1"> ... </div>
   <div id="flag1"> ... </div>
   <div id="flag1"> ... </div>
```

You close the outer  for the id="flag"

All those inner div elements actually have the same ID and should be switched to a class. Your CSS does't apply any styling to any ID's as it only apply styling to classes.

Some of your src attribute for your images don't have closing " on them and all of them point to so internal images we can't get access to.

There a difference in CSS between

```
.flag{ .. }        // apply to class
```

and

```
#flag { ... }      // apply to id
```

try something like this

```
<div id="flags">
  <div class = "flag">
     <span>A - ALPHA</span>
     <img src="..." title="..." border= "1"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "flag">
     <span>B - BRAVO</span>
     <img src="..." title="..." border= "1"/>
  </div>
  <div class = "flag">
     <span>C - CHARLIE</span>
     <img src="..." title="..." border= "1"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And assuming that your flags are 120 px wide by about 60px high then a starter CSS more like this will generate rows of 8 flags at a time:

```
#flags {
  width: 100%
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.flag {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:120px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:pink;
}
.flag span {
  display:block:
  width:100%
  height:40px;
}
.flag img {
  display:block:
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
}
```

Comment: you have to adjust the CSS to fit your images ( and make sure that you remove that white-space: pre-wrap as that makes it very hard to "guess" what height your divs will be ...